# How to configure IIS to run application in browser as "http://localhost/AppName/Default.aspx"

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I opened the application as a website from my visualstudio 2010 
So the application had this URL

```
"http://localhost:9698/AppName/Default.aspx"
```

Later, i added the application as website in IIS 7 and i got this URL

```
"http://AppName/Default.aspx"
```

Note : I used Appname in my Host file and Appname as Hostname in my IIS 7 settings..

Now, i need the URL to be "http://localhost/AppName/Default.aspx" 
when it runs from IIS...How can i change it ?

The reason i am doing this is, I need to provide this URL to my Facebook App
as Canvas URL. And Facebook dosent accepts "http://AppName/Default.aspx" as 
a valid domain. So i need to change the Apps localhost URL to

"http://localhost/AppName/Default.aspx"

How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is create a virtual directory named 'AppName' off of the default web site in IIS manager.  Point that virtual directory to the folder that is the root of your web app, and you're done.

`localhost` will already resolve to your loopback address, so no `hosts` file modification is necessary, and no IIS host headers will be needed either.  Your default web site should handle requests for `all unassigned`, IIRC.  In other words, eliminate any host headers from your default web site.  (though I suppose you could use `localhost` as a host header if you really wanted to...)

Comment: i tried as you said, the app is running in URL : http://localhost/default.aspx        But i need app name after localhost

Comment: @Anuya -- you have to create a virtual directory off of your default web site.  DO NOT create a new web site, use the default web site.  Actually, I just looked at my IIS manager:  add a new 'Application' instead, just to be safe.  Right click on your default web site, and click 'Add Application...'

Comment: yeah i got the URL as http://localhost/appname/default.aspx but..Getting Error : HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. Do i have to add in Host file ?\

Comment: Did you point the `appname` application to the directory which contains your default.aspx file?  If you're getting a 404, that means your web server is responding properly (so you don't need to modify `hosts`); it just can't find the file to serve.  Also, are you sure your default web site doesn't have any host headers associated with it?  We'd need to make sure IIS is serving from the proper web site

Answer (score 0):

The first section after the http:// is the server address.

Localhost is the machine on which you execute a command.

AppName isn't a valid domain name. That's why facebook won't accept it. You'll need to register a domain.

Answer (score 0):

first try to run this application on IIS but with default settings, ( without changes in Host file or IIS), url should be like this what you want. Then you'll have to change settings to use your IP instead of 'localhost'

Comment: I had some similiar problem with IIS Express. When i changed server from VS Express web server to IIS my url was same as url when i had used VS web server like localhost:8080/app/main.aspx . then i made changes in applicationhostconfig.config in IIS directory to use my ip instead localhost